# Creating instance of exported declared class ended up with 'is not a constructor' error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript function like this in an old .js file(and I have already referenced that using `<script>` in the .aspx file):

```
function myFunc(param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
}
```

My aim is to use the function in my .ts code like this:

```
var obj = new myFunc('test')
```

What I need to do is providing an interface and a class like this:

```
interface myFuncInterface {
}

export declare class myFunc implements myFuncInterface {
   public param1: any;
   constructor(param1);
}
```

So far so good. If I put the above piece of code in my .ts file, it works perfectly fine but if I put them into a type definition file then import it, there will be no compilation error but runtime error is raised like this:
**"myFunc is not a constructor"**

So many appreciate for your help

Comment: Are you using any module bundler?

Comment: No, I don't use any module bundler

Comment: Can you share how you transpile and include the generated files in your project? If you can create a small project that exhibits this behavior and share it here, I think we'll be able to help you out more.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do

Declare a class that takes a value in the constructor and has it as a public member

```
declare class myFunc {
  constructor(public param1: any);
}
```

## More

If old JavaScript behaves like new JavaScript then you can simply *declare* it to be new JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @Basarat but it shows this error:
'a parameter property is only allowed in a constructor implementation'

Comment: I have also updated the code of 'class myFunc' to be more precise but still same issue